# How to set custom build.gradle template for android new project with Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to set `repositories` of build.gradle file. Added this file not work.

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\build.gradle.ftl`